# kikoso/swipeable cards android

Tags: java, android, performance, github

hey i tried the kikose/swipeable-cards library but its performance isnt good(lags even on nexus 5 ). i tried to change the mMaxVisible in the cardContainer class from 3 to 2 the performance improved a little but still lags so i changes it to 1 and the performance looked very card on the first. after i swiped the first card the second isnt swipeable . the mTopCard in the cardcontainer class is null . how can i fix this or improve performance in others way maybe ?

here is the cardcontainer class :

```
public class CardContainer extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {
public static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private static final double DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS = Math.PI / 64;
private int mNumberOfCards = -1;
Context context;
private final DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        clearStack();
        ensureFull();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        super.onInvalidated();
        clearStack();
    }
};
private final Random mRandom = new Random();
private final Rect boundsRect = new Rect();
private final Rect childRect = new Rect();
private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();


//TODO: determine max dynamically based on device speed
private int mMaxVisible =2;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private int mFlingSlop;
private Orientation mOrientation;
private ListAdapter mListAdapter;
private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private View mTopCard;
private int mTouchSlop;
private int mGravity;
private int mNextAdapterPosition;
private boolean mDragging;
private boolean animating;
int index;
Profile cardModel;

public CardContainer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setOrientation(Orientation.Disordered);
    setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    init();
    animating = false;
}

public CardContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    initFromXml(attrs);
    init();
}

public CardContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    initFromXml(attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    ViewConfiguration viewConfiguration = ViewConfiguration
            .get(getContext());
    mFlingSlop = viewConfiguration.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
    mTouchSlop = viewConfiguration.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(),
            new GestureListener());
}

private void initFromXml(AttributeSet attr) {
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attr,
            R.styleable.CardContainer);
    setGravity(a.getInteger(R.styleable.CardContainer_android_gravity,
            Gravity.TOP));
    int orientation = a
            .getInteger(R.styleable.CardContainer_orientation, 1);
    setOrientation(Orientation.fromIndex(orientation));
    index = 0;
    a.recycle();
}
@Override
public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mListAdapter;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    index = 0;
    if (mListAdapter != null)
        mListAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);

    clearStack();
    mTopCard = null;
    mListAdapter = adapter;
    mNextAdapterPosition = 0;
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);

    ensureFull();

    Log.e("GETCHILD CARD CONT","getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1)==================="+getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1));
    Log.e("GETCHILD CARD CONT","getChildCount()==================="+getChildCount());

    if (getChildCount() != 0) {
        mTopCard = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        mTopCard.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }
    mNumberOfCards = getAdapter().getCount();
    requestLayout();

    ((Profile)adapter.getItem(0)).getOnCardDimissedListener().initialiseCard();
}

private void ensureFull() {
    while (mNextAdapterPosition < mListAdapter.getCount() && getChildCount() < mMaxVisible) {
        View view = mListAdapter.getView(mNextAdapterPosition, null, this);
        view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        if(mOrientation == Orientation.Disordered) {
            view.setRotation(getDisorderedRotation());
        }
        addViewInLayout(view, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                mListAdapter.getItemViewType(mNextAdapterPosition)), false);

        requestLayout();

        mNextAdapterPosition += 1;
    }
}

private void clearStack() {
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    mNextAdapterPosition = 0;
    mTopCard = null;
}

public Orientation getOrientation() {
    return mOrientation;
}

public void setOrientation(Orientation orientation) {
    if (orientation == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Orientation may not be null");
    if(mOrientation != orientation) {
        this.mOrientation = orientation;
        if(orientation == Orientation.Disordered) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                child.setRotation(getDisorderedRotation());
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                child.setRotation(0);
            }
        }
        requestLayout();
    }

}

private float getDisorderedRotation() {
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(mRandom.nextGaussian() * DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int requestedWidth = getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int requestedHeight = getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
    int childWidth, childHeight;

    if (mOrientation == Orientation.Disordered) {
        int R1, R2;
        if (requestedWidth >= requestedHeight) {
            R1 = requestedHeight;
            R2 = requestedWidth;
        } else {
            R1 = requestedWidth;
            R2 = requestedHeight;
        }
        childWidth = (int) ((R1 * Math.cos(DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS) - R2 * Math.sin(DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS)) / Math.cos(2 * DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS));
        childHeight = (int) ((R2 * Math.cos(DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS) - R1 * Math.sin(DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS)) / Math.cos(2 * DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS));
    } else {
        childWidth = requestedWidth;
        childHeight = requestedHeight;
    }

    int childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec;
    childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        assert child != null;
        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        boundsRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        View view = getChildAt(i);
        int w, h;
        w = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        h = view.getMeasuredHeight();

        Gravity.apply(mGravity, w, h, boundsRect, childRect);
        view.layout(childRect.left, childRect.top, childRect.right, childRect.bottom);
    }
}

int holdingCard;
View likeImage, dislikeImage;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mTopCard == null || animating) {
        return false;
    }
    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }


    final int pointerIndex;
    final float x, y;
    final float dx, dy;
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            getHitRect(mTopCard,childRect);
            pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

            if (!childRect.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                return false;
            }
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);


            float[] points = new float[]{x - mTopCard.getLeft(), y - mTopCard.getTop()};
            mTopCard.getMatrix().invert(mMatrix);
            mMatrix.mapPoints(points);
            mTopCard.setPivotX(points[0]);
            mTopCard.setPivotY(points[1]);

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

            dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            Profile profile = (Profile) getAdapter().getItem(0);

             likeImage = mTopCard.findViewById(R.id.like_text_image);
             dislikeImage = mTopCard.findViewById(R.id.dislike_text_image);


            if (mTopCard.getTranslationX() + dx > 30) {
                profile.getOnCardDimissedListener().tendToLike();
                dislikeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                likeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else if (mTopCard.getTranslationX() + dx < 30) {

                profile.getOnCardDimissedListener().tendToDislike();
                likeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                dislikeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                likeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                dislikeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            if (Math.abs(dx) > mTouchSlop || Math.abs(dy) > mTouchSlop) {
                mDragging = true;
            }

            if(!mDragging) {
                return true;
            }

            mTopCard.setTranslationX(mTopCard.getTranslationX() + dx);
            mTopCard.setTranslationY(mTopCard.getTranslationY() + dy);

            mTopCard.setRotation(40 * mTopCard.getTranslationX() / (getWidth() / 2.f));

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            if (!mDragging) {
                return true;
            }
            mDragging = false;
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(mTopCard,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationX", 0),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("translationY", 0),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("rotation", (float) Math.toDegrees(mRandom.nextGaussian() * DISORDERED_MAX_ROTATION_RADIANS)),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("pivotX", mTopCard.getWidth() / 2.f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("pivotY", mTopCard.getHeight() / 2.f)
            ).setDuration(250);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    animating = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    animating = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    animating = false;
                    dislikeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    likeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ((Profile) getAdapter().getItem(0)).getOnCardDimissedListener().cancelCard();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    animating = false;
                }
            });
            animator.start();

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
            final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);

                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

private void getHitRect(View v, Rect rect) {
    rect.left = (int) (v.getLeft() + v.getTranslationX());
    rect.top = (int) (v.getTop() + v.getTranslationY());
    rect.right = rect.left + v.getWidth();
    rect.bottom = rect.top + v.getHeight();
}

public boolean isAnimating()
{
    return animating;
}

public Profile getCurrentCard() {
    if(index + 1  > getAdapter().getCount())
        return null;
    Profile profile = (Profile) getAdapter().getItem(index);
    if (index + 1 == getAdapter().getCount())
        profile.setLast(true);
    return profile;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        Log.e("CARD CONTAINER","MTOPCARD =====================+++++++++ "+mTopCard);
        if (mTopCard == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        }
        final int pointerIndex;
        final float x, y;
        final float dx, dy;
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                getHitRect(mTopCard,childRect);
                Profile Profile = (Profile) getAdapter().getItem(0);

                if (Profile.getOnClickListener() != null) {
                    Profile.getOnClickListener().OnClickListener();
                }

                pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                if (!childRect.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                    return false;
                }

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
                if (Math.abs(x - mLastTouchX) > mTouchSlop || Math.abs(y - mLastTouchY) > mTouchSlop) {
                    float[] points = new float[]{x - mTopCard.getLeft(), y - mTopCard.getTop()};
                    mTopCard.getMatrix().invert(mMatrix);
                    mMatrix.mapPoints(points);
                    mTopCard.setPivotX(points[0]);
                    mTopCard.setPivotY(points[1]);
                    return true;
                }
        }

        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

}

@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public int getGravity() {
    return mGravity;
}

public void setGravity(int gravity) {
    mGravity = gravity;
}

public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {

    int viewType;

    public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
    }

    public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
    }

    public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public LayoutParams(int w, int h, int viewType) {
        super(w, h);
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }
}

private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        final View topCard = mTopCard;
        float dx = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        if (Math.abs(dx) > mTouchSlop &&
                Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY) &&
                Math.abs(velocityX) > mFlingSlop * 3) {
            float targetX = topCard.getX();
            float targetY = topCard.getY();
            long duration = 0;

            boundsRect.set(0 - topCard.getWidth() - 100, 0 - topCard.getHeight() - 100, getWidth() + 100, getHeight() + 100);

            while (boundsRect.contains((int) targetX, (int) targetY)) {
                targetX += velocityX / 10;
                targetY += velocityY / 10;
                duration += 100;
            }

            duration = Math.min(400, duration);

            cardModel = (Profile) getAdapter().getItem(0);


            if (cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener() != null) {
                if ( targetX > 0 ) {
                    {
                        if(MyUser.getInstance((Activity)context).getVip().equals("1") || (Float.valueOf((getCurrentCard()).getScore())>MyGenericApp.getInstance((Activity)context).getMinScoreMatch()))
                        {   
                            mTopCard = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 2);
                            if (mTopCard != null)
                                mTopCard.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

                            cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener().onLike();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener().forcedToDislike();
                            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    mTopCard = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 2);
                    if (mTopCard != null)
                        mTopCard.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

                    cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener().onDislike();

                }
                index++;
            }
            animating = true;
            topCard.animate()
                    .setDuration(duration)
                    .alpha(.75f)
                    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                    .x(targetX)
                    .y(targetY)
                    .rotation(Math.copySign(45, velocityX))
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            removeViewInLayout(topCard);
                            ensureFull();
                            if(getCurrentCard()!=null)
                                cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener().initialiseCard();
                             animating = false; 
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                            onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        }
                    });
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }


}

public void dislike(){

    final View topCard = mTopCard;

    View likeImage = mTopCard.findViewById(R.id.like_text_image);
    View dislikeImage = mTopCard.findViewById(R.id.dislike_text_image);
    dislikeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    likeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mTopCard = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 2);
    Profile cardModel = (Profile)getAdapter().getItem(0);

    if(mTopCard != null)
        mTopCard.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    animating = true;




    topCard.animate()
        .setDuration(400)
        .alpha(.75f)
        .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
        .x(-GlobalFunctions.getScreenWidth(context))
        .y(topCard.getY())
        .rotation(-45)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                removeViewInLayout(topCard);
                ensureFull();
                animating = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }
        });

    if(cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener() != null){
        cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener().onDislike();
    }
    index++;
    if(index < getAdapter().getCount())
        ((Profile)getAdapter().getItem(0)).getOnCardDimissedListener().initialiseCard();
}

public void like(){
    final View topCard = mTopCard;
    View likeImage = mTopCard.findViewById(R.id.like_text_image);
    View dislikeImage = mTopCard.findViewById(R.id.dislike_text_image);
    likeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dislikeImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    mTopCard = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 2);
    Profile cardModel = (Profile)getAdapter().getItem(0);

    if(mTopCard != null)
        mTopCard.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);


    animating = true;
    topCard.animate()
        .setDuration(400)
        .alpha(.75f)
        .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
        .x(GlobalFunctions.getScreenWidth(context))
        .y(topCard.getY())
        .rotation(45)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                removeViewInLayout(topCard);
                ensureFull();
                animating = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }
        });

    if(cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener() != null){
        cardModel.getOnCardDimissedListener().onLike();
    }

    index++;
    if(index < getAdapter().getCount())
        ((Profile)getAdapter().getItem(0)).getOnCardDimissedListener().initialiseCard();
}
```

}